# PNG image not scaling to full screen size

Tags: java, android

I have a splash screen on my android app, which is populated by a png image.  However the png image is not populating the full screen, there are spaces showing on the sides.

I am viewing this on and AVD.

Here is what I see:
[image: VIEW OF MY SPLASHSCREEN]

Here is my XML code:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent">

 <ImageView
 android:src="@drawable/splash"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"></ImageView>  

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is an extract of my Android Manifest code:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="5"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<supports-screens 
android:resizeable="true"
android:smallScreens="true" 
android:normalScreens="true" 
android:largeScreens="true"
android:anyDensity="true" />


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" 
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
            <activity
        android:name="com.shaadcorp.wazaifapp.MainMenu"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="ButtonMenu"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.shaadcorp.wazaifapp.CLEARSCREEN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>   
    <activity
        android:name="wazeefa"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.shaadcorp.wazaifapp.WAZEEFA" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="durood"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.shaadcorp.wazaifapp.DUROOD" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>

</manifest>
```

Please can any one help?  I have tried to increse the dimesions of the png itself but this makes no difference.

Comment: Add scaleType to your ImageView definition -http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the `android:scaleType` attribute to the `ImageView`. Probably `centerCrop` is what you want.

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/splash" />
```